# .NET upgrade from 4 to 4.6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, migration

Due to already end of life support of .net framework 4.0 business has planned to migrate the hosted web application that targets the 4.0 framework to 4.6.2 (EOL is 2027).
So we have asp.net web application hosted on the server (deployed binaries onto server) targetting the compilation framework 4.0 needs to migrate to 4.6.2,
My question is after changing the target framework version from 4.0 to 4.6.2 is it required to rebuild the application to achieve the goal?
Or just changing the framework version in webconfig file alone will be sufficient (without rebuild) to say the application has been upgraded from 4.0 to 4.6.2

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. Are you saying you've already made the application's binaries and deployed it to a server? The binaries have already been complied to target a specific runtime. In order to change that you'd need new binaries.

Comment: It's likely 4.8.1 is already being used, unless you are not updating your system

Comment: @gunr2171 currently I have asp net application targetting the compilation framework 4.0 and I want to upgrade to 4.6.2 as per the business requirements, so I am curious to know if i change the target framework of project from 4.0 to 4.6.2 without a rebuild will it be considered as upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can run a 4.0 application against a newer framework (which probably already happens, because all recent computers have only 4.8 installed), but no, this is not considered an update. That requires a rebuild.

But: Why would you want to upgrade from stone age to bronze age? The current .NET Framework version is 4.8.1, and anything older is out of support. Most applications will even easily update to .NET 6.0, and unless you are using components no longer supported, that is the way forward.

Comment: Net 6.0 is not a drop-in, though; there will be some code changes required.

Comment: Just to clarify, 4.6.2 and above is not out of support at this time (Aug 2023): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

Comment: @topsail Oh, I thought those where already OOS. But anyway, they will soon be, and the OP would just need to update again in half a year.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, but depending on the kind of application, the required changes are overseeable. The OP didn't specify what kind of application it is or how long he intents to still support it.

Comment: Support for 4.6.2 ends in January 2027.  There is no end date for 4.8.1.  The OP has some time.

Comment: Time well spent on gaining access to and understanding of the own source code as well as the .NET ecosystem as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends you review the following documents before you migrate your app from earlier versions of .NET Framework to version 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, or 4.8.1.

> - See [Versions and Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)
>   to understand the CLR version underlying each version of the .NET
>   Framework and to review guidelines for targeting your apps
>   successfully.
> - Review [Application compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/application-compatibility)
>   to find out about runtime and retargeting changes that might affect
>   your app and how to handle them.
> - Review [What's Obsolete in the Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-obsolete)
>   to determine any types or members in your code that have been made
>   obsolete, and the recommended alternatives.
> - See [What's New](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/)
>   for descriptions of new features that you may want to add to your app.

Refer to the [NET Framework Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/) for further information - these are the docs you want to be familiar with when you are planning an upgrade like this one.

To answer your specific question the documentation about version compatibility states that

> by default, an app runs on the version of .NET Framework that it was
> built for. If that version isn't present and the app configuration
> file doesn't define supported versions, a .NET Framework
> initialization error may occur. In this case, the attempt to run the
> app will fail.

Again, refer to the same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/) for further information. There is some detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5) about how a version of the .Net runtime will be activated for the app to run on. But I think you can take this mean that you may or may not succeed if you try to run your application on a framework that it was not compiled (or tested) against. On the other hand - you can "test in production" and see what happens ;)